# List and Invalidate a particular session

Tags: spring

We are using spring mvc application

1. How to list all the sessions stored in the server ?
2. How to invalidate a particular session which is active in the server - session id is available ?

Comment: By Session(s) you mean logged in user(s)?

Comment: Yes. Logged in users. Tried with Security.getContext.getAllPrinciples() and retrieve session and invalidate it. Is this is the right way or any other best approach to do this?

Comment: Any Comments on this?